# Change colour of event on full calendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I know this sounds silly but I'm really struggling with the event colours on the fullcalendar.

I've gone through the css and changed all the blue to maroon but for some reason when I put in a holiday that's more than a week it changes it to blue.

Am I being stupid or is it something really easy to rectify?

http://www.bigwood.nottingham.sch.uk/calendar

Go to the July month to see what I mean.

I've even screen printed the webpage, got the colour reference numbers and gone into Dreamweaver to try and find where the blue colours are but can't seem to find them.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the color of all events using:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   eventColor: '#yourcolor'
});
```

Based on full calendar documentation http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventColor/

Answer (score 0):

If you change   `background-color: #760D09` to  `background-color: #760D09 !important;`
It will do the trick for you. But `!important` is advised not to use very often.

```
.fc-event {
    background-color: #760D09 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
```

Comment: Although this probably works, you'd better use fullCalendar API to set events' color (see @jcarlo's answer)